# Basic Tic Tac Toe in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to make a simple tic tac toe Game in Java and I'm almost done but my program doesn't declare a winner and doesn't declare if the game is a draw or not even when in my code I told it to declare a winner.

Here is my code:

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class TicTacToe {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static int row, colm;
public static char board[][] = new char [3][4];
public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
public static char turn = 'X';

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            board[i][j] = '_';
        }
    }

    board();
    play();
    winner(row,colm);
}

public static void board() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if(j == 0) {
                System.out.print("|");
            } else {
                System.out.print(board[i][j]+"|");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void play() {
    boolean playing = true;
    while(playing) {
        row = console.nextInt();
        colm = console.nextInt();
        board[row][colm] = turn;
        if(winner(row,colm)) {
            playing = false;
            System.out.print("you win");
        }
        board();
        if(turn == 'X') {
            System.out.println("Player 2 your O");
            turn = 'O';
        } else
            turn='X';
    }
}

public static boolean winner(int move1, int move2) {
    if(board[0][move2] == board[1][move2] && board[0][move2] == board[2][move2])
        return true;
    if(board[move1][0] == board[move1][1] && board[move1][0] == board[move1][2])
        return true;
    if(board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[0][0] == board[2][2] && board[1][1] != '_')
       return true;
    if(board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[0][2] == board[2][0] && board[1][1] != '_')
       return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: closing braces missing for `winner` function

Comment: In my code I already have that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: at least make the code more readable

Comment: First, make your code readable. Second, check the errors: You don't even have your braces balanced.

Comment: I just tried that and after entering a row and colm it automatically declares a winner

Comment: tried that too and I'm running into the same problem

Comment: The last part declares the winner. So if player 1 does gets 3 X in a row diagonally or in a straight line than it would say player 1 is the winner or vice versa.

Comment: This is the actual code

Comment: yea i was going add"the winner is"+ turn but before I did i was trying to make it to work and it didn

Comment: i'm trying it and is not working for me. Could you do it and paste the code here because this is my first year taking java and I'm messing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is done like that, then `turn` will have the wrong value after someone has won and you want to display it in `main`, here are the corrections:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    board();
    play();
    // remove winner(row,colm); it isn't doing anything here
    // turn has the right value of the winner here if play() is modified
}

public static void play() {
    // remove boolean playing = true; it is not needed
    for (;;) { // I call it the 'forever', but you can also write while(true)
        ...
        board[row][colm] = turn;
        board(); // move up unless you don't want to display the board on wins
        if (winner(row,colm)) {
            System.out.print(turn + " you win");
            return; // (or break) <-- otherwise turn has the wrong value in main
        }
        ...
    }
}
```